# Parsing Projection WKT in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am looking for a method (javascript) (external or internal part of ol3) that can parse a projection WKT to its proj4 text and create the projection.

```
 <SRS>PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 53",GEOGCS["GDA94",DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",135],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","28353"]]</SRS>
```

Above shows an example of the XML element containing the SRS.

I have found out that if I can convert this to proj4 text. Then i can add it as a projection this way:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28353", "+proj=utm +zone=53 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

var def = proj4.defs(grid.srs);
var units = def.units;
        var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: grid.srs,
            units: units,
            axisOrientation: def.axis
        });
        proj.setExtent(/*...*/);
        ol.proj.addProjection(proj);
        var proj4Transform1 = proj4('EPSG:3857', grid.srs);
        ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'), proj,
            proj4Transform1.forward, proj4Transform1.inverse);
        var proj4Transform2 = proj4('EPSG:4326', grid.srs);
        ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'), proj,
            proj4Transform2.forward, proj4Transform2.inverse);
```

Is it possible to find the extend of the projection in the WKT also or should I look this up also external?

Comment: Please post this problem in [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) and you will get more response from there. Which is for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals

Comment: OpenLayers questions are on-topic here, and stackoverflow is the preferred platform for openlayers-3 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proj4js supports WKT strings too. You can throw what you have (excluding the `<SRS>` tag) directly at proj4js, using the same syntax:

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:28353", "PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 53",GEOGCS["GDA94",DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",135],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","28353"]]");
```

Once you have defined a projection using `proj4.defs()`, it will be immediately be available in OpenLayers 3, and all transforms will be registered. So the `proj4.defs()` line is all you need unless you want to set additional options, like the projection extent in your case. There are two options to do this: 1) globally:

```js
ol.proj.get('EPSG:28353').setExtent(*/ ... */);
```

or 2) just for one `ol.proj.Projection` instance that you use to e.g. configure your `ol.View`:

```js
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:28353',
  extent: /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the reason why I have to add teh coordinate transforms myself is that I am loading with AMD loaders after ol3 has been loaded. I am guessing that for ol3 to pick them up itself, it need to be added together with proj4 before ol3 loads? You agree?

Comment: Right, and this could be considered a bug in ol3. ol3 currently expects Proj4js to be provided as `proj4` in the global namespace. See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/2333#issuecomment-82170569 for a potential fix, in case you want to provide a pull request.